# Salt Proxy Minion Concept

Tags: salt-stack

We are testing Salt Stack open source for one of our internal project. Basically we would want to automate few things on windows machines using salt but we don't want to install salt minions (not allowed in our environment) or use salt ssh (since we don't have openssh or any other ssh server on windows in our environment).

We thought salt proxy minion would solve our purpose but its confusing how it is configured. We would like to know if salt proxy minion would solve our requirements or please suggest a solution for our situation. Our use cases are like

1. Get Windows Machines details using WMI remotely
2. Run other Remote Machine commands for reading details on the machine

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. If you can't install configuration management software like Saltstack, then use native Windows capabilities such as [Powershell's remote execution tooling and Windows remote management (WinRM).](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)

It's fairly easy once you've configured your environment to support WinRM to do WMI queries on remote machines.

Salt Proxy Minions are intended for things like embedded devices such as networking equipment, serial-only devices, and so forth -- not for managing full Windows clients.